# Trying to add cinnamon to gentoo - gives me a masked warning

Tags: linux, kernel, gentoo

So I am trying to add cinnamon for a desktop environment for my Gentoo machine, so far I have done the install well, and gotten to the part with the `x-server`, though I am having trouble getting the actual `Cinnamon` desktop environment to install.

I run the command: `emerge --ask gnome-extra/cinnamon` and I get the following error messages:

```
All ebuilds that could satisfy "gnome-extra/cinnamon" have been masked.
One of the fllowing masked packages is required to complete your request:
 - gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.0.7-r1::gentoo (masked by: ~amd64 keyword, invalid: REQUIRED_USE: USE flag 'python_targets_python3_3' is not in IUSE
 - SAME MESSAGE BUT FOR gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.0.7::gentoo
 - SAME MESSAGE BUT FOR gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.0.6::gentoo
 - SAME MESSAGE BUT FOR gnome-extra/cinnamon-2.8.8

For more information, see the MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge
man page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.
```

Here's my `USE flags` in `/etc/portage/make.conf`

```
USE="X python_targets3_3 bindist git networkmanager nls pulseaudio icu gnome-keyring opengl jpeg"
USE_PYTHON="3.4"
PYTHON_TARGET="python_targets_python3_3"
```

Now here's my `/etc/portage/package.mask`:

```
libtool openrc perl
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, and `=gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.0.7-r2` is available directly in the portage tree now. So a simple `emerge gnome-extra/cinnamon` should do as of today. The reference information is on the [Gentoo Wiki Cinnamon](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Cinnamon) page.

On my vanille GNOME system the output is like this:

```
# emerge --ask --tree gnome-extra/cinnamon

These are the packages that would be merged, in reverse order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.0.7-r2::gentoo  USE="networkmanager     nls" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 -python3_4" 2.994 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/nemo-3.0.6::gentoo  USE="exif introspection nls (-packagekit) {-test} -tracker -xmp" 1.332 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/cinnamon-control-center-3.0.1::gentoo  USE="colord cups systemd -debug" INPUT_DEVICES="-wacom" 3.745 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  x11-wm/muffin-3.0.5::gentoo  USE="introspection {-test} -xinerama" 2.655 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/cinnamon-screensaver-3.0.1::gentoo  USE="pam systemd -debug -doc" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 144 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/cinnamon-session-3.0.1::gentoo  USE="ipv6 systemd -doc" 579 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/cinnamon-settings-daemon-3.0.1::gentoo  USE="colord cups systemd -smartcard {-test}" INPUT_DEVICES="-wacom" 2.845 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]   gnome-extra/cinnamon-desktop-3.0.2:0/4::gentoo  USE="introspection systemd" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 565 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/cjs-3.0.1::gentoo  USE="cairo gtk -examples {-test}" 318 KiB
[ebuild  NS    ]   dev-lang/spidermonkey-24.2.0-r4:24::gentoo [1.8.5-r6:0/mozjs185::gentoo, 38.2.1_rc0:38::gentoo] USE="system-icu -debug -icu -jit -   minimal -static-libs {-test}" 15.262 KiB
[nomerge       ] x11-wm/muffin-3.0.5::gentoo  USE="introspection {-test} -xinerama" 
[ebuild  N     ]  app-text/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10-r1::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 515 KiB
[nomerge       ] gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.0.7-r2::gentoo  USE="networkmanager nls" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 -python3_4" 
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/cinnamon-menus-3.0.2::gentoo  USE="introspection -debug" 207 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  dev-python/pypam-0.5.0-r3::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 -python3_4 -python3_6" 103 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  dev-python/pyinotify-0.9.6::gentoo  USE="-examples" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 (-pypy) (-pypy3) -python3_4 -python3_6" 60 KiB
[nomerge       ] app-text/gnome-doc-utils-0.20.10-r1::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 
[ebuild  N     ]  app-text/scrollkeeper-dtd-1.0-r1:1.0::gentoo  11 KiB
[nomerge       ] gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.0.7-r2::gentoo  USE="networkmanager nls" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 -python3_4" 
[ebuild  N     ]  dev-python/pexpect-4.2.1::gentoo  USE="-doc -examples {-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 (-pypy) (-pypy3) -python3_4 -python3_6" 141 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]   dev-python/ptyprocess-0.5.1::gentoo  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 (-pypy) (-pypy3) -python3_4 -python3_6" 67 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  dev-python/polib-1.0.7::gentoo  USE="-doc" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 -python3_4 -python3_6" 153 KiB
[ebuild  N     ]  gnome-extra/cinnamon-translations-3.0.3::gentoo  7.753 KiB

Total: 19 packages (18 new, 1 in new slot), Size of downloads: 39.440 KiB
```

For future versions this is how installing a keyword masked package would work as per the [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Working/Portage#Masked_packages). Say you find the portage tree makes you want to go bleeding edge with `=gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.6.6.-r2`, then you'd manually accept a keyword for it:

```
$ eix -s cinnamon

* gnome-extra/cinnamon
 Verfügbare Versionen:   3.0.7-r2 ~3.2.0-r2 ~3.2.6-r1 ~3.2.7-r1 ~3.4.2-r1 ~3.4.6 ~3.6.6-r2 {+networkmanager +nls PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5"}
 Startseite:             http://developer.linuxmint.com/
 Beschreibung:           A fork of GNOME Shell with layout similar to GNOME 2
```

As per the Knowledge Base, [add an entry specific to the version](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:Accepting_a_keyword_for_a_single_package) marked with `~` you want to `/etc/portage/package.keyword/gnome-extra`

```
# echo "=gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.6.6-r2" >> /etc/portage/package.keywords/gnome-extra
```

And then `emerge` this package atom (and see here for [Sakaki's wiki page for terminology](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Installing_the_Gentoo_Stage_3_Files#Atoms.2C_Packages.2C_Categories.2C_Versions.2C_Sets_and_SLOTs)). I added `--pretend` to have it show what would be done:

```
# emerge --ask --verbose --pretend --tree =gnome-extra/cinnamon-3.6.6-r2
```

The resulting list will likely give you more packages that would need unmasking. You may then decide which version to use depending on follow-up version changes that one package might need, repeat the command while omitting `--pretend` when you're done. Check into [portage options for adding a keyword and autounmasking](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Knowledge_Base:Autounmask-write) for more details.